# Improve ugly PSTricks code

Tags: pstricks, code-review, pstricks-add

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\psset{unit = 0.47\psunit, fillstyle = solid}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0.5,1)(25,12.7)
\psframe(3,1)(10,10)
\psframe[fillcolor = blue!70](3,1)(10,4)
\rput(6.5,2){Saltvand}
\psframe[fillcolor = red!60](3.5,2)(4,12)
\psframe[fillcolor = gray!60](9,2)(9.5,12)
\psframe[fillcolor = black](1,11.7)(3,12.3)
\psline[linewidth = 3\pslinewidth](2.9,12.23)(3.75,12)
\psline[linewidth = 3\pslinewidth](2.9,11.77)(3.75,12)
\psframe[fillcolor = black](12,11.7)(10,12.3)
\psline[linewidth = 3\pslinewidth](10.1,12.23)(9.25,12)
\psline[linewidth = 3\pslinewidth](10.1,11.77)(9.25,12)
\psframe[fillcolor = gray!80](14,1)(24,9)
\psframe(15,4)(21,8)
\psarc[linewidth = 0.75\pslinewidth](18,5){2}{30}{150}
\multido{\i = 30+40}{4}{%
  \psRelLine[angle = \i, linewidth = 1.5\pslinewidth](18,5)(20.3,5){1}{A}
  \psRelLine[angle = \i, linecolor = white, linewidth = 2.5\pslinewidth](18,5)(19.7,5){1}{A}%
}
\multido{\i = 50+40}{3}{
  \psRelLine[angle = \i, linewidth = 0.75\pslinewidth](18,5)(20.3,5){1}{A}
  \psRelLine[angle = \i, linecolor = white, linewidth = 2\pslinewidth](18,5)(19.7,5){1}{A}%
}
\psline[origin = {18, 5},linewidth = 2\pslinewidth](2.5;120)
\psframe(17,2.4)(19,2.6)
\psframe[fillcolor = black](17.2,2.2)(17.8,2.8)
\rput(16,2.5){\large $=$}
\rput(20,2.5){\large $\sim$}
\pscircle(23,2.7){0.5}
\pscircle(23,2.7){0.2}
\rput(21.8,2.7){\large $-$}
\pscircle(23,4.2){0.5}
\pscircle(23,4.2){0.2}
\rput(21.8,4.2){\large $+$}
\rput(23,1.7){\scriptsize $0$/Jord}
\rput[t](22.5,8){\shortstack[c]{%
  \footnotesize Volt-\strut\\[-0.75ex]
  \footnotesize meter\strut}
}
\psset{fillstyle = none}
\psline(1,12)(0.5,12)(0.5,12.7)(25,12.7)(25,2.7)(23,2.7)
\psline(12,12)(24.5,12)(24.5,4.2)(23,4.2)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The output is as I would like it, but the code is not very pretty. Especially the `\multido` stuff is badly written; can anyone help me improve this?

Comment: Well, for me the code is pretty. A figure with a lot of pieces ans shapes should be a huge code.

Comment: @Sigur You might be right. `:)` I just don't think it looks very good for some reason. Especially the thing with the display (the `\multido` stuff) is surely not done the best way.

Comment: -1 That's not a question; that's code review.

Comment: @Jubobs How do I ask for help on that?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I see; didn't knew of that side. How do I migrate my question from here? I've never done that before.

Comment: @Jubobs I suppose there was meta thread http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3541/tagging-please-improve-my-code-posts that without a `code-review` tag Q can be closed and some voice against code-review migration also. May be adding `code-review` tag to this Q would be appropriate

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: write such _question_ to the PSTricks mailing list and nobody will complain .... ;-)

Comment: @Herbert I'l remember that. Thank you for the notice.

Comment: I think `pstricks`  tag should always be included whenever any PSTricks-based questions are posted such that we don't need to subscribe to all tags of other packages "derived" from `pstricks`. What do you think?

Comment: I think you need to apply OOP-like paradigm to your code to make it easy to read and maintain. For example, it will be better if you create macros `\def\Solution` for the left container filled with solution and `\def\Voltmenter` for the right voltemeter. Then in `pspicture` you use both of them probably with `\rput` calls to reposition them. What do you think? One of benefits: The used coordinates for one object are independent on those for other objects.

Comment: @StiffJokes That is a good point. I'll remember that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `\multido` can be simplified:

```
\multido{\i=30+40}{4}{\psline[origin={18,5},linewidth=2\pslinewidth](1.75;\i)(2.25;\i)}
\multido{\i=50+40}{3}{\psline[origin={18,5}](1.75;\i)(2.25;\i)}
```

and maybe the two circles are the same as `\psRing`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\psset{unit=0.47cm,fillstyle=solid}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0.5,1)(25,12.7)
\psframe(3,1)(10,10)
\psframe[fillcolor = blue!70](3,1)(10,4)
\rput(6.5,2){Saltvand}
\psframe[fillcolor = red!60](3.5,2)(4,12)
\psframe[fillcolor = gray!60](9,2)(9.5,12)
\psframe[fillcolor = black](1,11.7)(3,12.3)
\psline[linewidth = 3\pslinewidth](2.9,12.23)(3.75,12)
\psline[linewidth = 3\pslinewidth](2.9,11.77)(3.75,12)
\psframe[fillcolor = black](12,11.7)(10,12.3)
\psline[linewidth = 3\pslinewidth](10.1,12.23)(9.25,12)
\psline[linewidth = 3\pslinewidth](10.1,11.77)(9.25,12)
\psframe[fillcolor = gray!80](14,1)(24,9)
\psframe(15,4)(21,8)
\psarc[linewidth = 0.75\pslinewidth](18,5){2}{30}{150}
\multido{\i = 30+40}{4}{\psline[origin={18,5},linewidth=2\pslinewidth](1.75;\i)(2.25;\i)}
\multido{\i=50+40}{3}{\psline[origin={18,5}](1.75;\i)(2.25;\i)}
\psline[origin = {18, 5},linewidth = 2\pslinewidth](2.5;120)
\psframe(17,2.4)(19,2.6)
\psframe[fillcolor = black](17.2,2.2)(17.8,2.8)
\rput(16,2.5){\large $=$}
\rput(20,2.5){\large $\sim$}
\psRing(23,2.7){0.5}{0.2}
\rput(21.8,2.7){\large $-$}
\psRing(23,4.2){0.5}{0.2}
\rput(21.8,4.2){\large $+$}
\rput(23,1.7){\scriptsize $0$/Jord}
\rput[t](22.5,8){\shortstack[c]{%
  \footnotesize Volt-\strut\\[-0.75ex]
  \footnotesize meter\strut}}
\psset{fillstyle=none}
\psline(1,12)(0.5,12)(0.5,12.7)(25,12.7)(25,2.7)(23,2.7)
\psline(12,12)(24.5,12)(24.5,4.2)(23,4.2)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the improvement is still possible, for example, the obvious one, removing `\psset{fillstyle=none}` at the third row from above the `\end{pspicture}`. Unfortunately, I cannot post my answer anymore.

Comment: @StiffJokes I can't remove `\psset{fillstyle=none}` as it is now. (Try to do that and see what happens.) It is unfortunate that you can't post your answer. `:(`